# Autocomplete with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Just type any one leter (egs, "c") you will get the list and select the item.
But in the model the complete name is not being saved, it will only saving the first character you input.

But if you click the item on the list and hit space then the whole item is going to be saved.

I want the moment i select the list the item name has to save inn model.

http://plnkr.co/edit/JDPqHfgMzSBHsa9InHxi?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
    <h4 class="text-center txtC1">Enter your medicines</h4>
    <input type="text" ng-keypress="complete()" ng-model="enteredName" id="tags" />
    <p>{{enteredName}}</p>
    <p class="rr txtC2">Type</p>
    <select id="dd" ng-model="sel">
        <option value="Days">Days</option>
        <option value="Tabs">Tab</option>
        <option value="Packs">Pack</option>
    </select>
    <p class="rr txtC2">Qty</p>
    <input type="number" class="rr" ng-model="ww" id="dd" />
    <br />&nbsp
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center ">
        <button id="btn2" ng-click="addName()">Add</button>
        <button id="btn2">Order</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p class="txtC1">
            Cart
            <hr>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 dd1">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="tt" ng-repeat="name in names">
                {{name.x1}} x {{name.tp}} x {{name.qty}}
                <a class="fa fa-close tt1" ng-click="removeName(name)">remove</a>
                <a class="fa fa-edit tt1" ng-click="edit(name)">edit</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


 app.controller('NameCtrl', function ($scope){

   $scope.availableTags = [
"Combiflame ",
"Crocine",
"Alphine",
"Nitro",
"Betnisol",
"Daliy Dose",
"Eyetone",
"Kyrotop",
"ramtop",
"Glizid-M"
];

    $scope.complete=function(){
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: $scope.availableTags
    });
    } 




if($scope.ww != ''){
         $scope.names = [


        ];}
        else{

        }


        $scope.addName = function() {

    console.log (    $scope.names)    

if($scope.ww != ''){

     $scope.names.push({'x1':$scope.enteredName,'tp':$scope.sel,          'qty':$scope.ww});
          $scope.enteredName = '';

 $scope.ww = '';
 $scope.tp = '';


}else
{

}



        };

        $scope.removeName = function(name) {
          var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
          $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
        };





      $scope.edit = function(name){

           var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);

        $scope.enteredName = name.x1; 
        $scope.sel = name.tp;
        $scope.ww = name.qty;

           $scope.names.splice(i, 1);


      }


      });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your are using jquery auto complete with in angular. When the value changed by jquery, it will not digest angular. That is, when auto complete changes your text value, it will not change it's corresponding model inside the angular.

To fix this situation, I strongly recommend you to use angular's bootstrap.

You can find it here.[Bootsrap_Angular](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

For your reference how you can do auto complete using angular, `check this one` [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9zsrvLLfH8hKGwmIeZVv?p=preview)